# How would I go about using a float that I modified in one function into a main function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a float number called r1x that I modified in a function. I want to use that float number in the main function. I tried declaring it a global var, but it still gives me an error saying it's undefined.

```
import tkinter
import random
def random_location_no():
    global r1x
    #global r1y
    print('no pressed')
    r1x = round(random.uniform(0.6, 0.8), 2)
    r1x = float(r1x)
    print(r1x)
    return r1x
    
    
def main(): 
    global window
    #global r1x
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title ('iq test')
    window.geometry('800x800')
    
    txt = tkinter.Label(window, text = ' Are you stupid :3', font = ("Oswald", 45, "bold"))
    txt.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.22, anchor="c")
    
    no_button = tkinter.Button (window, text = 'No', fg = 'Black', height = 5, width = 10, command = random_location_no, font = ('Finlandica', 15))
    no_button.place(relx = r1x, rely = 0.55, anchor = 'c')
    
    yes_button = tkinter.Button (window, text = 'Yes', fg = 'Black', height = 5, width = 10, command = yes_press, font = ('Finlandica', 15))
    yes_button.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.55, anchor = 'c')
    
    
    
    window.mainloop()

main()
```

in the code, r1x is a float in the function random_location_no.

I want to use r1x in the main function, in line 24.
I tried declaring it as a global var, but it still gives me the error.

Any ideas are appreciated! Thanks

Comment: If you can post your code that'll make it easier to help you :)

Comment: hey thx for the suggestion. I tried copy and pasting my code, but the formatting was messed up for some reason. I opted to sent a raw text link instead

Comment: Please show the actual error.

Comment: my fault @BryanOakley i forgot about that. But i'm past that now so it's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare something as a global variable inside a function, it doesn't get defined until that function actually gets run. `no_button.place(relx = r1x, rely = 0.55, anchor = 'c')` does run the function, but it also calls for `r1x` to already be defined, so you'd have to either run your function once first before doing `no_button.place(relx = r1x, rely = 0.55, anchor = 'c')`, or initialize `r1x` to some value at the beginning of your main function.

Answer (score 0):

You **shouldn't** use global variables, maybe just pass first function as an argument to the second function like this:

```
def generate_number():
    return 10

def get_number(func):
    return func()

get_number(generate_number)
```

or in your case just do it like this:

```
def random_location_no():
    ...
    ...
    return r1x

def main(random_number): 
    number = random_number()
    ...
    ...

main(random_location_no)
```

---

and for your information, when ever you call the function, variables are created at the call time, so, local (or even global variables that you make them global by passing **global keyword**) life time finished when the function return, so, if u want to get the value return from a function u need to call it in another function.

Comment: hey thanks for the comment!
in your example, the main(random_location_no) is not really sending a number. I return r1x to the function random_location_no, but number isn't really holding anything.
I added a print (number) statement and it's not showing anything.

Comment: I don't clearly understand what you mean. but as I said, you can have a function A. function A return something. in function B, pass function A as an argument. so whenever you call function B and send function A as a parameter to function A, then function A called and returned value of that can be saved in a local variable of function B.